# Fastest Way to Deactive Webhooks

Tags: podio

Concerning Podio webhooks:

I have a desire to deactive hooks that I identify as no longer being relevant to my app's need. My problem is that it's possible that my app no longer has authorization to do a delete hook. The api docs say:

> The hook must respond with a 2xx status code. If the status code is different from 2xx more than 50 consecutive times the hook will return to being unverified and will have to be verified again to be active. Additionally, your hook may return to unverified if you do not send responses in a timely manner. You should handle any heavy processing asynchronously.

How long does the delay need to be to qualify as not "in a timely manner"? Or is there a better/faster way to deactivate the hooks without authorization? I don't always want to wait for 50 consectutive times.

Answer (score 0):

If webhook is not needed you should delete it: [Delete hook method](https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/delete-hook-215291) 
If app is no longer authorized to delete webhook, then I'd respond with 4xx error, something like `410 Gone` seems to be most appropriate answer in such case.

"In a timely manner" means 15 seconds. It's mentioned here: https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks